# Tag merge: 'ssi' and 'server-side-includes'

Tags: support, retag-request

Seems like a good candidate for merger. Only one question in each. Or should it be handled with a simple re-tag?

Comment: Also? Woot on our very own meta.

Comment: My very first question on the original Meta was for this. Nice to see it's finally come to fruition!

Answer (score 3):

Small mergers like this should just be done with a manual retag (which I've done).  It's when you start to get boatloads of them that a mod should get involved and to a mass retag.  Basically, if a manual retag is going to be a big pain or if it's going to clutter up the front page with a bunch of bumped questions request a mod do it.

Comment: I also put a proposal down for a tag synonym [ssi] => [server-side-includes]

Comment: Thanks for the best-practices guide!

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't every tag merge become a [tag synonym](https://serverfault.com/tags/synonyms) as well?